# How to compile tflite with GPU support?

Tags: java, c++, delegates, gpu, tensorflow-lite

I try to compile tflite for Android with GPU support

```
bazel build --cxxopt='--std=c++11' -c opt --fat_apk_cpu=arm64-v8a //tensorflow/lite/java:tensorflowlite_gpu
```

but I get several error messages like:

```
./tensorflow/lite/delegates/gpu/gl/gl_call.h:60:29: error: no viable conversion from returned value of type 'tflite::gpu::Status' to function return type 'int'
    if (status.ok()) return OkStatus();
```

Do I need to pass any other command line params to bazel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the `-DMESA_EGL_NO_X11_HEADERS` flag. See https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/27320